# How to make a Makefile that adds a line of code to a .cpp? (#include .h)

Tags: c++, makefile

For this project I have 3 files: driver.cpp, bet.cpp and bet.h.

When I submitted this project I edited driver.cpp to have #include bet.cpp. The issue is that driver.cpp was supposed to remain unedited. I cannot resubmit the files I can only resubmit a Makefile.

So the challenge is to create a Makefile that somehow adds the line "#include 'bet.h'" to the bet.cpp file so that it can run on my teacher's end correctly.

To add a little more context. I messed up and edited driver.cpp. This resulted it in working on my end but a compilation error on my teacher's end. Compilation error is a deduction of 50 points, I've talked to her and she can't bend the rules even to a minor 1 line of code mistake.

But if the Makefile were to be the only issue she could regrade and only deduct points for that.

Here are the original headers for each of the files:

```
driver.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "bet.h"
...

bet.cpp: 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <sstream>
...

bet.h: 
#ifndef ASSIGNMENT_3_BET_H
#define ASSIGNMENT_3_BET_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
...
```

This is a Makefile GPT suggested. It didn't work.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra

driver: driver.o bet.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o driver driver.o bet.o

driver.o: driver.cpp bet.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c driver.cpp

bet.o: bet.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DBET_INCLUDE_HEADER -c bet.cpp

clean:
    rm -f driver *.o
```

Any ideas? or is it impossible to fix this issue by only editing a makefile?

Comment: Possible or not it's hard to believe that this is what your teacher intends you to do. Talking to your teacher about the issue seems more sensible.

Comment: That's not, what makefiles are usually doing. But you could add `sed` commands to change the files before compiling.

Comment: `-include "bet.h"`

Comment: Re: "driver.cpp [has] `"#include bet.cpp"`" -- don't do that. Ever. The makefile you've shown manages the two source files correctly (although I'm not clear on what the point of `-DBET_INCLUDE_HEADER` is).

Comment: "This is a Makefile GPT suggested. It didn't work". Well, obviously. Why would it?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, your teacher requires you to implement a horrible Make-kludge to patch a code error which has been set in stone by a stupid and arbitrary policy. I'd call that a bad lesson, but I've seen the same thing happen in production, so...

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the file itself would result in `bet.o` always being out of date, so you could use Eljay's suggestion from the comments or generate a new source file from `bet.cpp` that becomes the source for building `bet.o`.

```
...

driver.o: driver.cpp bet.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c driver.cpp

bet_fixed.cpp: bet.cpp
    echo '#include "bet.h"' | cat - bet.cpp > bet_fixed.cpp

bet.o: bet_fixed.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DBET_INCLUDE_HEADER -c bet_fixed.cpp -o bet.o

clean:
    rm -f driver *.o bet_fixed.cpp
```